# Google Sync the calendar on iOS

Tags: ios, calendar

I am quite new to iOS, and I would appreciate if you can give me a clue on how to tackle this issue.

I am planning a mobile application and a cloud service to require "Google calendar is sync with the calendars on mobile devices" ( namely iPhone, iPad, and Android )

On Android, I can read calendar's event id from our Android app. If I change event attributes such as tile and time etc, the event id stays unchanged, and it seems to be a good way to associate our meta data to it (i.e. event id).

On iOS side, if I enable Google Sync, the events I defined on web still appear on the calendar on iOS. My question is "Can I problematically get event id that are assigned on Google Calendar?"

The following link says 
"EKEvent's eventIdentifier is likely to be changed when event changes"
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/EKEvent/eventIdentifier
... so my guess is that this field does not reflect event id from Google calendar.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the event identifier is of the form:

> 88E45678-2S11-574E-ABF8-3B1E463ERF4C:google_calendar_id@google.com

for a google sync calendar event.

If there was a change made to one of the recurring calendar events the identifier can also have exception date at the end:

> 88E45678-2S11-574E-ABF8-3B1E463ERF4C:google_calendar_id@google.com<!ExceptionDate>20121025